# Why Cookies with SameSite=None aren't sent within an <iframe> in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: python, flask, cookies, iframe, samesite

I created a simple Web Server that sets a cookie with SameSite=None and Secure flag and tried to check if this cookie was then inserted in the next request made via Iframe

I created this simple Web Server with Flask, which sets a Cookie with SameSite=None and Secure flag... I expose it on **http://127.0.0.1:5000**:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    response = make_response('Cookie Set!')
    
    # Set the cookie with SameSite=None and Secure flag
    response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'cookie_value', samesite='None', secure=True)
    
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I open firefox and navigate to **http://127.0.0.1:5000**, the "*my_cookie*" is set correctly within the browser.
If I subsequently open the following HTML page with Firefox which contains an iframe with http://127.0.0.1:5000:

```
<html>

<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:5000" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-same-origin" > </iframe>

</html>
```

By intercepting the HTTP request, I don't see the cookie that is set and sent for the request in the iframe... But I don't understand why.

Thanks so much

Comment: What is the URL of the HTML page that contains the iframe? Or do you open it from the file system, without a web server? In that case, the cookie could be blocked as a third-party cookie (see [tag:third-party-cookies]).

Comment: Yes... I'm opening it as HTML page from file system.

Comment: That explains why the cookie is treated as third-party and blocked by your browser. Try serving the HTML page also from your Flask server.